# Как сделать поиск и добавить друга в контакте ?

Tags: php, вконтакте

Как сделать поиск и добавить друга в контакте ? - не прошу всего кода, ссылочку бы на документацию или примеры, если кто встречал, я впервый раз этим интересуюсь. Спасибо.

Comment: В идеале планирую написать код, с помощью которого смогу искать единомышленников по неким полям, город, пол, интересы.

Comment: напомнило историю) [Про чувака и mySpace](https://habrahabr.ru/company/ua-hosting/blog/270599/)

Answer (score 2):

1. Метод [users.search()](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=users.search) — искать пользователей по какому-то критерию;
2. Добавить в друзья: [friends.add()](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=friends.add) — этот метод доступен только мобильным/десктоповым приложениям.